# Execute jquery ajax after page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

To describe scenario that I want to make:
When user goes to stackoverflow.com the page is loaded fast.
And in the top right corner there are 2 menu items (inbox, achievements).
I have the same looking page.
But as I need more time to load this items that cause that page load slower.
How can I execute `JQuery ajax function` to get those data after all data on page are already loaded.
Basicaly: **Load whole page** > **execute jquery and display results when you get them**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() { /* Ajax call */ });
```

Or if you prefer shorter notation, just use:

```
$(function() { /* Ajax call */ });
```

Comment: Thanks I came from asp.net CMS world where I have to do some voodoo magic to achive this. So I forgot .ready() :)